# Adding additional columns to SQLite database table

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have been working on an android app for a while now, and have gotten it to the point where I have handed it in and received my grade already. However, I have been playing around with it in my spare time, and would like to upgrade it a little. To summarize what my app does so far:

- Allows user to create a list of classes
- Allows user to create a list of assignments for those classes
- Allows user to edit classes/assignments

I have recently been getting a force close after editing my helper class for the assignments. I have been able to narrow down where the issue is originating.

```
return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, assname, urge, name, assday, assmonth FROM assignments ORDER BY "+ orderBy, null));
```

it seems like that particular statement is giving me an error in both instances that it appears.

```
return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, assname, urge, name, assday, assmonth FROM assignments WHERE _ID=?", args));
```

When I remove *assday* and *assmonth* from both of those statements and stop the program from adding them to the content values, the error goes away.

All I want to do is add a column for the due date and month so I can display it on the assignments list. I know how to do this, however the error is stopping me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will have to give more information, such as what comes in orderBy. Have you checked validity of your information?

Comment: Did you increase the version # of your database after you added your new columns? It won't recognize database changes unless you increase the version number.

Comment: i like a good challenge but we shouldn't have to guess your stack trace

Comment: How exactly do you add these columns to the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry for the vague question and for the slow response times. I was careless in attempting to implement this feature and managed to overlook adding the columns to the table in the "CREATE TABLE" statement. I apologize for everybody's wasted time.

Before: `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE assignments (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, address TEXT, type TEXT);");`

After: `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE restaurants (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, address TEXT, type TEXT, assday TEXT, assmonth TEXT);");`

Since I have two helper classes (which I have been informed is a bad idea, and I now see why) I forgot to edit the one whose onCreate() is called. I once again am sorry for the negligence on my part.